# Append values to specific column openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

Trying to take a set of data from ws2 and append to the bottom of ws3. I'm struggling to append to a specific column on ws3.

Currently, everything just appends to column A, although I want it to append to the same columns where the information is coming from in ws2.

```
#where I want to copy data from:
for col in ws2.iter_cols(min_row=2,min_col=4,max_col=6):
    for cell in col:
        ws3.append([cell.value])

wb3.save('example3.xlsx')
```

Help!

Comment: *"appends to column A"*: `append(...` works **rowwise**. You have to use: `ws3.cell(row=<current row>, column=<current column>).value = cell.value`

Answer (score 2):

You can only append rows, but you can easily adjust your code to work with this:

```
for col in ws2.iter_rows(min_row=2,min_col=4,max_col=6):
    row = [None]*3 + [cell.value for cell in col]
    ws3.append(row)
```

Comment: Using your code I changed `ws3.append([cell.value])` to `ws3.append(row)` and it appended to the correct column! Thank you. Since there is already content in Column A, is there a way to append the rows in the correct column next to the content that already exists in Column A, rather than below it ? As in append to the same rows as the content that already exists in Column A?

Comment: If you want to work using columns you have to use `ws.cell()`. In your case however, you could use `zip(ws2.iter_cols(…), ws3.iter_cols(…)`

Answer (score 2):

Now, in 2020, there's a way more handy way to solve this:

from the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.append)

```
append(iterable)

Appends a group of values at the bottom of the current sheet.

    If it’s a list: all values are added in order, starting from the first column
    If it’s a dict: values are assigned to the columns indicated by the keys (numbers or letters)

Parameters: iterable (list|tuple|range|generator or dict) – list, range or generator, or dict containing values to append

Usage:

    append([‘This is A1’, ‘This is B1’, ‘This is C1’])
    or append({‘A’ : ‘This is A1’, ‘C’ : ‘This is C1’})
    or append({1 : ‘This is A1’, 3 : ‘This is C1’})

Raise:  TypeError when iterable is neither a list/tuple nor a dict
```

So, in your code, it should be something like:

```
ws3.append({col: cell.value})
```

Comment: This still appends to next after last row which may not be the next free row in the required column.